# TagName Input not displayed in my ember View

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, jsfiddle, jsbin

I want my ember view displaying the result of the total calculation in an input in order to get the value binding of the result.

Everything works fine a part from that i can not get the result inside my Input number

This is my view

```
App.TotalView = Ember.View.extend({
 tagName: 'input',
 templateName:"total",
 attributeBindings: ['value', 'placeholder'],
 placeholder: null,
 value: '',
 total: (function() {
    var res= parseInt(this.get('controller.newThread.selectContentTariffa')) * parseInt(this.get('controller.newThread.primary'));
   return isNaN(res)?"":res;
    }).property('controller.newThread.selectContentTariffa', 'controller.newThread.primary')
});
```

This is my html

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="total">
    {{view.total}}
  </script>
```

Why the result is displayed out of the input?

I have reproduced the issue here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/piqihi/edit?html,js

>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok check this one [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qagocunumo/1/edit?html,js,output) you have this in your view value: '', and then total: (calculation) just replace value: (your calculation) with out total property.

Comment: i saw that there was also this way  attributeBindings: ['total:value', 'placeholder']